# Cannot use Step Object in Cest Codeception

Tags: codeception

Following this tutorial https://codeception.com/docs/06-ReusingTestCode#StepObjects, but something simple is probably missing..

I have a StepObject class here:

> tests/_support/Step/Acceptance/Admin.php

```
<?php
namespace Step\Acceptance;

class Admin extends \AcceptanceTester
{

    public function loginAsAdmin()
    {
        $I = $this;
    }

}
```

I documentation it says:

```
StepObject can be instantiated automatically when used inside the Cest format:
```

And gives this example

```
class UserCest
{
    function showUserProfile(\Step\Acceptance\Admin $I)
    {
        $I->loginAsAdmin();
    }
}
```

But how do I use this `showUserProfile` method inside the Cest file, for example inside the `_before` section?

I tried `$this->showUserProfile();` but it says `[ArgumentCountError] Too few arguments to function` . It's not accepting the $I object. What should I pass to it and how?

Should I be requiring/referencing something somewhere?

And how can I use this class inside helper modules?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that you want to use the Helper functionality in Codeception.

Just find the correct helper class. The default one is `tests/_support/Helper/Acceptance.php` and add your method there...

```php
<?php 

namespace Helper;

// here you can define custom actions
// all public methods declared in helper class will be available in $I

use Codeception\Module;

class Acceptance extends Module
{
    public function loginAsAdmin()
    {
        // ... your login here
    }
}
```

Make sure that the helper is activated in your `codeception.yml` and also be aware of to run the `codecept build` command to regenerate the auto-generated AcceptanceTester class. If you need the AcceptanceTester class to do assertions, you can add it as one function parameter.

If anything works as expected, you can just use your AcceptanceTester in your Cest without any extra dependency injection:

```php
class UserCest
{
    function showUserProfile(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->loginAsAdmin();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the method is `showUserProfile` method which executes the StepObject method is executed automatically when the test is ran, as per:

*Each public method of Cest (except those starting with _) will be executed as a test*

So it looks like the StepObject is not designed to be called at will, it just runs when the test is executed.

If someone has a better answer I'll gladly accept it.